# Remover lista vazia em Python

Tags: python, lista

```
os.chdir(pasta)   
lista = []
 for air in os.walk('.'):
  if lista != []:
    lista.append(air)
     print(lista)
```

Alguém poderia me dizer por que eu não consigo imprimir as pastas?

Se eu tirar o `if`, aparece as pastas, mas também aparece `[]`.

```
[('.', ['Game_play', 'Menu', 'Settings', 'Setup'], ['testes.json']), ('.\\Game_play', ['tc001.air', 'tc002.air', 'tc003.air'], []), ('.\\Game_play\\tc001.air', [], ['tc001.py']), ('.\\Game_play\\tc002.air', [], ['tc002.py']), ('.\\Game_play\\tc003.air', [], ['tc003.py']), ('.\\Menu', ['tc001.air'], []), ('.\\Menu\\tc001.air', [], ['tc001.py']), ('.\\Settings', ['tc001.air'], []), ('.\\Settings\\tc001.air', [], ['tc001.py']), ('.\\Setup', ['tc001.air'], []), ('.\\Setup\\tc001.air', [], ['tc001.py'])]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Eu não consigo imprimir só as pastas sem essas `[]` sem nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não funciona porque a lógica do seu código está errada.

O objeto `lista` começa com o valor `[]`, uma lista vazia e só sofre alteração, isto é, um novo elemento é adicionado, se a condição `if lista != []` for satisfeita. Isso é quase paradoxal com o seu objetivo. Aliás, por que verificar se a lista em questão é vazia aqui?

O retorno da função `os.walk` é uma tupla que possui os valores: `root`, diretório raiz da estrutura em questão, `dirs`, lista de diretórios dentro de `root`, `file`, lista de arquivos dentro de `root`.

Se a ideia é apenas listar diretórios que possuem sub-diretórios, você precisará verificar que `dirs`, do retorno de `os.walk`, é uma lista vazia. Algo como:

```
for air in os.walk('.'):
  if air[1]:
    lista.append(air)
```

Se está utilizando o Python 3.4 ou superior, recomendo que estude o módulo [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).